# Android room query is empty when using Flow

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am confused about using `Flow` with `Room` for database access. I want to be able to observe a table for changes but also access it directly.
However, when using a query that returns a `Flow`, the result always seems to be `null` although the table is not empty. A query that returns a `List` directly, seems to work.

Can someone explain the difference or show me which part of the documentation I might have missed?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db_button.setOnClickListener {
            val user_dao = UserDatabase.getInstance(this).userDatabaseDao

            lifecycleScope.launch {
                user_dao.insertState(State(step=4))

                val states = user_dao.getAllState().asLiveData().value
                if (states == null || states.isEmpty()) {
                    println("null")
                } else {
                    val s = states.first().step
                    println("step $s")
                }

                val direct = user_dao.getStatesDirect().first().step
                println("direct step $direct")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "state")
data class State(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "step")
    var step: Int = 0
)

@Dao
interface UserDatabaseDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertState(state: State)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM state")
    fun getAllState(): Flow<List<State>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM state")
    suspend fun getStatesDirect(): List<State>
}
```

Output:

```
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: direct step 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Room`, we use `Flow` or `LiveData` to observe changes in a query result. So `Room` queries the `db` asynchronously and when you are trying to retrieve the value immediately, it is highly probable to get `null`.

As a result, if you want to get the value immediately, you shouldn't use `Flow` as the return type of a room query function, just like what you did on `getStatesDirect(): List<State>`. On the other hand, if you want to observe data changes, you should use the [**collect**](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow#collect) terminal function on the `Flow` to receive its emissions:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    user_dao.insertState(State(step=4))

    val direct = user_dao.getStatesDirect().first().step
    println("direct step $direct")
}

lifecycleScope.launch {
    user_dao.getAllState().collect { states ->
        if (states == null || states.isEmpty()) {
            println("null")
        } else {
            val s = states.first().step
            println("step $s")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. One more question: If I change the code to the one you posted, the last print (with the "direct step") does not show up anymore. What's the reason for that?

Comment: NP :) As the `collect` is a suspend function, it suspends the execution of the launched coroutine. So, you should put the `direct step` above it, or put the `collect` into another coroutine.